# $1^2,2^2,3^2,\cdots,n^2 $ leave different remainders

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility

> If $2n+1$ is a prime number, show that $1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2,\dots,n^2$ when divided by $2n+1$ leave different remainders.

Please provide a solution to this.

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Let $1\leq a<b\leq n$. Show that the prime $p:=(2n+1)$ does not divide $$b^2-a^2=(b-a)(b+a).$$
Note that $1\leq (b-a)<(b+a)<2n$.

Comment: @Mrigank Shekhar Pathak. Any further doubt or comment?